# Angular 16 Jasmine Error: Expected one matching request for criteria, found none

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have seen lots of questions about this error but having spent the best part of today trying each solution out I need your help.

I have a **function** that I use to send data from a form to a URL (not yet defined).

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.formPassword.valid) {
      const formData = new FormData();

      let letEmail: string = this.formPassword.value['email']!;

      formData.append('email', letEmail);

      this.http.post<any[]>('URL-BACK', formData).subscribe({
        next: (respuesta: any) => {
          this.requestSuccess = true;
          if (respuesta == 0) {
            console.log('Error al enviar la solicitud');
            this.requestSuccess = false;
            this.formPassword.reset();
          } else {
            console.log('Solicitud enviada con éxito');
            this.requestSuccess = true;
            this.formPassword.reset();
            this.showSuccess();
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
            }, 5000);
          }
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log('complete');
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error('Error al enviar la solicitud', error);
          this.requestSuccess = false;
          this.showError();
          this.formPassword.reset();
        },
      });
    }
  }
```

More TYPESCRIPT:

```
formPassword: UntypedFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  });

isInvalid(campo: string) {
    return (
      this.formPassword.controls[campo].errors &&
      this.formPassword.controls[campo].touched
    );
  }

check(): void {
    console.log('información enviada:', this.formPassword.value);
    this.onSubmit();
  }
```

And HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="formPassword" (ngSubmit)="check()">
    
      <div class="mb-4">
        <input
          [ngClass]="{ 'ng-invalid ng-dirty': isInvalid('email') }"
          type="email"
          pInputText
          formControlName="email"
          placeholder="Correo electrónico"
          aria-describedby="email-help"
        />
        <small *ngIf="isInvalid('email')" id="email-help" class="p-error block"
          >La dirección de correo no es válida</small
        >
      </div>

    </form>
```

I'm trying to pass this test through jasmine but I'm getting this error (I share also part of the SPEC.TS so you can see what I have imported).

**SPEC.TS**

```
describe('ForgotPasswordComponent', () => {
  let component: ForgotPasswordComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ForgotPasswordComponent>;
  let messageService: MessageService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let router: Router;
  const api_server = 'http://localhost:4200';

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ForgotPasswordComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [UntypedFormBuilder, HttpClient, HttpHandler, MessageService],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ForgotPasswordComponent);
    messageService = TestBed.inject(MessageService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

**TEST JASMINE**

```
it('should handle a successful POST request', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'showSuccess'); 

    component.formPassword.setValue({ email: 'example@example.com' });

    component.onSubmit();

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('URL-BACK');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    req.flush(1); 

    expect(component.showSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

> **ERROR**: *Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: URL-BACK", found none*.

Seeing some of the forum's answers I have tried several options but all of them give me errors, I share two of them (I only put the modified code so that it is not too long)

> **ERROR** *Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: GET, URL: (any)", found none.*

```
it('should call showSuccess and navigate when the form is valid and the request succeeds', () => {

    const req = httpMock.expectOne({
      method: 'GET',
    });
    console.log('req is ' + req);
    expect(req.request.params.toString()).toBe(
      '${urlParam.param}=${urlParam.value}'
    );
    req.flush('Some');

  });
```

> **ERROR**: *Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:4200/auth", found none.*

```
it('should call showSuccess and navigate when the form is valid and the request succeeds', () => {
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${api_server}/auth`);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(1);

    httpMock.verify();
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you only perform the request when the form is valid, any chance that it's invalid? Can't tell because the code to create the form is not part of the question...

Comment: The form can only be submitted when the email you enter is valid, I'll update the post by adding the HTML and a bit more Typescript if that makes it clearer. Thank you very much.